# Posting a data model to ActionResult from partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to submit form data to an MVC3 controller from a partial view. For some reason the submitted data model is never populated.

This is the jquery handling the form submission:

```
        $(document).on('submit', '#FormNewCall', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax(
            {
                async: true,
                type: "POST",
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#callTable").replaceWith(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error submitting call");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    CloseNewCall();
                }
            })
        });
```

The reason I'm using "on" (First line) is because the partial view that contains "FormNewCall" is added   via jquery/ajax only when it is needed.

The ActionResult in the controller looks like this:

```
    // POST: /Default/SubmitCall/
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitCall(ServiceCallModel SubmittedModel)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
              // Do things before returning a new view
        }
        else
        {
            return View(); 
        }
    }
```

The actual form is a partial view with many things like this:

```
    <div class="rowContainer">
        <tr class="SmallRow">
            <td>@Html.Label("Brief")
            </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewCallModel.description)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
```

When I setup breakpoints in the controller, the parameter "SubmittedModel" is present but has all empty values.

It appears as if the property "Request.Form" is a json string with all of the expected data from the submitted form.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Default model binding doesn't work that way. It's not going to pull apart a JSON string for you. You could write a custom model binder to do that. Otherwise you need to post one `Request.Form` variable for each matching property on your view model.

Comment: It also seems like `$(this).serialize()` will serialize the jQuery object, not the form data.

Comment: if m => m.NewCallModel is property of type ServiceCallModel, so posted data is prefixed with "NewCallModel." (for example name of input for description is "NewCallModel.description"). So default model binder can't bind posted values to model. You can pass NewCallModel to partial view (So your helpers will looks like @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.description) and posted data will be without prefixes. Or you can change name of argument in action method to newCallModel ( public ActionResult SubmitCall(ServiceCallModel newCallModel) and model binder will try this prefix during binding.

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643864/how-do-i-render-a-partial-form-element-using-ajax/19643974#19643974

Comment: Please refer my answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023259/how-to-format-json-for-asp-net-webmethod-that-takes-class-parameter/21026621#21026621].
In this answer consider value of object property is your form control value in ajax calling side.