# Using MVC4 how can you submit the [HttpPost] action without a submit button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Typically I would create a submit button to post data, but in this case I want the [HttpPost] action to post on page load. This page is collecting data from other sources and there is no need for the user to hit submit.

Comment: use an ajax call.  see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643864/how-do-i-render-a-partial-form-element-using-ajax/19643974#19643974

Answer (score 4):

simply use ajax call, imagine that a get action returns the list of tags like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var tags = _tagRepository.GetAllTag();
        return View(tags);
    }
```

now in the view of index you have all tags, and also want to add the remove capability, now you can do this by ajax call:

```
@model IList<Blog.Domain.Model.Tag>

//list of tags here 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".delete").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var link = this.href;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'Post',
                    url: link,
                    success: function (data) { }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and about the post action:

```
   [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Delete(int tagId)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _tagRepository.RemoveTag(tagId);
                _tagRepository.Save();
                RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return Json("");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use AJAX, you can simply submit the form with jQuery:

```
$('form').submit();
```