# how to call actionresult method in my controller from kendo grid in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, methods, kendo-ui, actionresult

I want to pass id to my actionresult method Delete

```
 public ActionResult Delete(Guid AssetTypeId)
    {
        //  _repo.DeleteAssetType(AssetTypeId);
        if (_repo.DeleteAssetType(AssetTypeId) == 1)
        {
            return Index();
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["AlertMessage"] = "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint ";
            return Index();
        }
```

from kendo grid

```
.Action("Delete", "AssetType",new { AssetTypeId = "#=AssetTypeId#"  }))
```

Comment: use an ajax call,  see my answer here for an example on how to do it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643864/how-do-i-render-a-partial-form-element-using-ajax/19643974#19643974

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have AssetTypeId declared in your schema. In that case you don't need to send it separately. You just need to catch your Model in Delete. For deleting it should look like following; you can see details in their official demo site in [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing-popup.html).

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult EditingPopup_Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ProductViewModel product)
        {
            if (product != null)
            {
                productService.Destroy(product);
            }

            return Json(new[] { product }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
```