# How to dynamically load partial views MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view, partial-views

I have a index view page that has tower menu items. When any of the menu items are clicked I would like to load a partial view.

I'm use to working with web usercontrols, but this seems to be somewhat different.

In the code below the ActionResult Index contains the tower of menu items.

When the index view is loaded it looks like the snap shot below.

[image: Index partial view]

```
    public class EnterpriseManagerController : AlumCloudMvcControllerBase
    {
        public class PhotoViewModel
        {
            public int Width { get; set; }
            public int Height { get; set; }
            public short MaxPhotoBytes { get; set; }
            public string GenericPhoto { get; set; }
            public bool IsLogo { get; set; }
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public PartialViewResult Avatar()
        {

            var x = new PhotoViewModel { Width = _avatarwidth, Height = _avatarheight, MaxPhotoBytes = _maxavatarbytes, GenericPhoto = _genericLogo };

            return PartialView(x);
        }
}
```

When ever the menu item Avatar is clicked I would like to load the _AvatarPartial on the right side of the tower of menu items. When the EnterpriseManagerController Avatar PartialViewResult is called I would like to pass the PhotoViewModel to the PartialView(x).

**The code for my Index.cshtml looks like:**

```
    <div id="controlPanWrap">
        @Html.Partial("_VerticalMenuPartial")

   //I NEED TO LOAD THE PARTIAL VIEWS RIGHT HERE
    </div>
```

**This is what my Avatar partial view looks like:**

```
_AvatarPartial.cshtml
```

How to I load the Avatar partial view to have the content of the `_AvatarPartial.cshtml` fit right in the cent of:

```
    <div id="controlPanWrap">
        @Html.Partial("_VerticalMenuPartial")

   _AvatarPartial.cshtml
    </div>
```

And when some other menu item is click have that `_SomeOtherMenuItemPartial.cshtml` fit into that space and the `_AvatarPartial.cshtml` be removed?

**If this can be done with JavaScript without reloading the entire page would be great.**

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643864/how-do-i-render-a-partial-form-element-using-ajax/19643974#19643974

Comment: You could try using ajax to call a method in your controller that returns a PartialView.  Then you can render the contents of that partial view into your content div... Alternatively you can see the answer from the guy above me :)

Comment: The only thing that is holding me back is the fact that each one of the views has their own scripts.

Comment: I gave you a one up for helping. I should have mentioned that I've got little scripts and styles for a few of the views. It's only natural to have a few here and there.. I've posted how to retrieve the views and process the scripts and styles.

Answer (score 0):

The uiHelper.getHTML is just a wrapper around a XMLHttpRequest object.

```
setTimeout(function () {

    var prevLi = document.getElementById('liAvatar');
    var liOnclick = function () {
        if (this === prevLi) { return; };
        prevLi.removeClass('li-selected');
        prevLi = this.addClass('li-selected');


        uiHelper.getHTML({
            url: '/enterprisemanager/' + this.innerHTML, isAsync: true, cache: true, successCallback: function () {

                var scripts = this.substring(this.indexOf('<script') - 7, this.lastIndexOf('<\/script>') + 9);
                var styles = this.substring(this.indexOf('<style'), this.lastIndexOf('<\/style>') + 8);

                var that = this.replace(scripts, '');
                that = that.replace(styles, '');


                var newScript = document.createElement('script');
                newScript.setText(scripts.replace('<script type="text/javascript">', '').replace('<\/script>', '')).setAttr('id', 'script_' + prevLi.innerHTML);
                document.head.appendChild(newScript);

                var newStyle = document.createElement('style');
                newStyle.setText(styles.replace('<style type="text/css">','').replace('<\/style>','')).setAttr('id', 'style_' + prevLi.innerHTML);
                document.head.appendChild(newStyle);

                document.getElementById('controlPanOpt').innerHTML = that;
            }
        });

    };
    document.body.selectorAll('.controlPanOpts li', function () {

        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].onclick = liOnclick;
        };

    });
}, 1500);
```

--My prototypes

```
HTMLStyleElement.prototype.setText = function (txt) {
    /// <summary>Sets the textContent of this HTMLStyleElement to the txt param</summary>
    /// <returns type="this" />
    if ('textContent' in this) { this.textContent = txt || ''; } else { this.innerText = txt || ''; };
    return this;
};
HTMLScriptElement.prototype.setText = function (txt) {
    /// <summary>Sets the textContent of this HTMLScriptElement to the txt param</summary>
    /// <returns type="this" />
    if ('textContent' in this) { this.textContent = txt || ''; } else { this.innerText = txt || ''; };
    return this;
};
HTMLElement.prototype.setAttr = function (name, val) {
    /// <summary>Adds a new name and value attribute that are the name, val params</summary>
    /// <param name="name" type="String">Name of attribute to create onto this HTMLElement</param>
    /// <param name="val" type="String">Value to set the new name attribute being added onto this HTMLElement</param>
    /// <returns type="this" />
    this.setAttribute(name, val); return this;
};
```