# Ajax.BeginForm PartialView not refreshing

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using asp.net mvc 4. I've searched many other similar questions here, but they didn't help.

I want to refresh my partial view - FileList after uploading file.
Instead I see now redirecting to page with updated file list, but i want to refresh this list in partial view. :(. Can anybody help? Another solutions to do similar features are acceptable :)

My partial view is in another (index) partial view.

Here is FileController:

```
private static int folderId = 0;

public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    folderId = id;
    this.GetFiles();
    return PartialView();
}

public PartialViewResult FileList()
{
    this.GetFiles();
    return PartialView("FileList");
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public PartialViewResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> filesToUpload)
{
        this.UploadFilesToBase(filesToUpload, 1);

    this.GetFiles();

    return PartialView("FileList");
}
```

and here is Index.cshtml

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/main.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "File", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod =             "POST", UpdateTargetId = "FilesListDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   <div class="btn-upload-file">
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      <span class="btn"><span>Upload file</span></span>
      <input type="file" class="file" name="filesToUpload" multiple    onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();"><br>
    </div>

 }

<div id="FilesListDiv">
   @*@Html.Action("FileList", "File")*@    
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/File/FileList.cshtml")
</div>
```

and here is my FileList.cshtml

```
 @{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "Files";
 }

 @foreach (MyProj.Web.DataContracts.File file in ViewBag.Files)
 {         
    file.Name
 }
```

Comment: see my answer here for how I refresh partial views http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643864/how-do-i-render-a-partial-form-element-using-ajax/19643974#19643974

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax form doesn't work, probably because you haven't included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` into the page and as a result, it works like a regular html form.

As soon as you add this file, you will be able to refresh the content via ajax, but `filesToUpload` will be `null` in the controller. The reason for that is impossibility of uploading files via ajax, because it does not support `multipart/form-data` enctype.

You can try to use some jQuery upload plugins ot [HTML 5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications).

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ and this will submit form without the refresh. When you got the file uploaded on server then you can make a callback on the success of upload.

Get the list of file from server as render as html (through partialresult) and update them on client side browser.