# How to make a submit button with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to write a code that takes the last name and first name from user input and stores the values in a data table with MVC4. I have added the following code under Accountcontroller.cs

that will create a submit button. Once the user clicks the submit button it would add the user input to the data set.

```
private void button_Click( object sender, EventArgs e) 

{ 
   SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source = FSCOPEL-PC; ....

   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

   da.insertCommand = new SqlCommand(" INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ( Firstname, Lastname,  )
}
```

I have also added the following code under logincs.html that will create the submit button, once the user logins.

```
   <button type="submit" id="btnSave" name="Command" value="Save">Save</button>
```

Comment: It looks like you try to combine ASP.NET WebForms with ASP.NET MVC...

Comment: this is not the way that MVC works.  To accomplish what you are wanting you either need to do a postback and save the user that way or do an ajax call.  see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643864/how-do-i-render-a-partial-form-element-using-ajax/19643974#19643974 for how to do that

Answer (score 16):

In MVC you have to create a form and submit that form to the Controller's Action method. The syntax for creating form given as:

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourActionName", "ControllerName"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

**Controller:**

```
  public ActionResult YourActionName(UserModel model)
       {
          //some operations goes here
          return View(); //return some view to the user
       }
```

**Model:**

```
public class UserModel
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to have `id="btnSubmit"` declared in this sample, correct?

Comment: It was the sample code and Id is used in some jquery function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form method="post">
 //Here you need to add the code for textboxes
 <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" 
 formaction="@Url.Action("ControllerActionMethodName")" formmethod="post" />
 </form>
 //Afterwards inside the controller you need to decorate the actionmethod 
 with  [httppost] attribute on top of the action method,
 then you will be able to see the submit button functionality working well.
```

After adding  this code on click of submit button, you  will notice the debugger hitting the action method.