# How to use C# class in code written in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I am making an application. There is a form and I am trying to save the information entered from this form into Microsoft SQL Server. I haven't been able to get to the save part yet because I can't access the save class yet.

Code:

`addClass.cshtml:`

```
@page
@model AddClassPage
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add Class";
}

<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white">
    <h2 class="display-4">Add Class</h2>
</div>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="teacherIdInput">Class ID (number only):</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" id="classId" name="classId" placeholder="Class ID">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="teacherNameInput">Class Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="classNameID" name="classNameID" placeholder="Class Name">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-grey">Add</button>
</form>
```

`Database.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace StudentWebApp.Pages.Shared
{
    public class Database
    {      
        SqlConnection? connection;
        SqlCommand? command;
        SqlDataAdapter? adapter;

        public void ClassRecord(int Id, String ClassName)
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=(localdb)\local; Initial Catalog=Class; Integred Security=SSPI");
            connection.Open();
            string write = "INSERT INTO Class(ClassId, Name), VALUES(@ClassId, @Name)";

            command = new SqlCommand(write, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassId", Id);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Id);

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to access the `Database` class from the `Database.cs` file and run the `ClassRecord` method. But I don't know how to access Database.cs in `AddClass.cshtml` file. I couldn't find any information.

How can I do that?

When I press the Add button, I want the `RecordClass` method from the database class to run.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a submit button with MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659771/how-to-make-a-submit-button-with-mvc-4)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a service layer between your back end (your Database class), and your front end (the .cshtml page).

Usually you will want a WCF or a WebAPI service running on the server, that your web app can call.

Comment: So how can I add this service layer? How can I code? Can you leave sample code?