# JQuery Dialog box opens before MVC update Partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to open up a dialog modal window during a button click event and when I open this window, I want to be able to call a view which gets the latest information and updates the modal dialog with the correct information when it loads. But it is always grabbing the first record and display that. When looking through the code, it opens the dialog box, then it goes and runs the code for the action result, but the View never gets updated with the correct record.

So I have a dropdown list of shipping addresses. I want to get the ID of selected record, which I get, pass that to the ActionResult Method, which I have done, get my data I need and open a dialog box and pass it the information I want to be displayed, however it's not updating with what I pass it because the modal has already popped up with the original modal value I guess of the first address in the list, not the currently selected one that I have, if that makes sense.

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult PublicInfo(string widgetZone)
    {
        var address = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.Addresses
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == _workContext.CurrentCustomer.ShippingAddress.Id);

        PublicInfoModel model = new PublicInfoModel();

        model.FirstName = address.FirstName;
        model.LastName = address.LastName;
        model.Address1 = address.Address1;
        model.Address2 = address.Address2;
        model.City = address.City;
        model.StateProvinceId = 1;
        model.StateProvinceName = address.StateProvince.Name;
        model.CountryId = 1;
        model.CountryName = address.Country.TwoLetterIsoCode;
        model.PostalCode = address.ZipPostalCode;

        return View("Nop.Plugin.Widgets.AddressVerification.Views.WidgetsAddressVerification.PublicInfo", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PublicInfo(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.selectedShippingId = id;

        var address = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.Addresses
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);

        PublicInfoModel model = new PublicInfoModel();

        model.FirstName = address.FirstName;
        model.LastName = address.LastName;
        model.Address1 = address.Address1;
        model.Address2 = address.Address2;
        model.City = address.City;
        model.StateProvinceId = 1;
        model.StateProvinceName = address.StateProvince.Name;
        model.CountryId = 1;
        model.CountryName = address.Country.TwoLetterIsoCode;
        model.PostalCode = address.ZipPostalCode;

        return View("Nop.Plugin.Widgets.AddressVerification.Views.WidgetsAddressVerification.PublicInfo", model);
    }
```

Model:

```
@model Nop.Plugin.Widgets.AddressVerification.Models.PublicInfoModel

<div id="dialog-modal" style="display:none;">
    @Html.Partial("Nop.Plugin.Widgets.AddressVerification.Views.Shared._Address", Model)
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#shipping-buttons-container .new-address-next-step-button")[0].onclick = null;
        $("#shipping-buttons-container .new-address-next-step-button").click(function () {
            newContent();
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                // For modern browsers
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                // For older IE browsers
                e.returnValue = false;
            }


            //Shipping.save();
        });

        function newContent() {
            $(function () {
                var selectedShippingAddressId = $('#shipping-address-select').val();
                //alert(selectedShippingAddressId);
                if (selectedShippingAddressId != null) {
                    $('#dialog-modal').dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        width: 500,
                        resizable: false,
                        title: 'An updated address has been determined, would you like to use this one?',
                        modal: true,
                        open: function (event, ui) {
                            var url = '@Url.Action("PublicInfo", "WidgetsAddressVerification")';
                            $.post(url, { id: selectedShippingAddressId });

                        },
                        buttons: {
                            "Close": function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Just to get the currently selected information to popup in modal.

Comment: use an ajax call to get the partial on the page and then open the dialog.  see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643864/how-do-i-render-a-partial-form-element-using-ajax/19643974#19643974

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure how you want this to flow, but to update the content of your modal you just need to update your dialog-modal div with a partial view pulled down from your ajax call something along these lines for the js

```
$("#shipping-buttons-container .new-address-next-step-button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "@Url.Action("PublicInfo", "WidgetsAddressVerification")",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#dialog-modal").html(data);
                $('#dialog-modal').modal('show'); 
            }
        });
    });
```

with a controller that passes back html in a partial view so it doesn't include the _Layout template and is just the raw html.

```
public PartialViewResult PublicInfo(string widgetZone)
    {
        var address = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.Addresses
        .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == _workContext.CurrentCustomer.ShippingAddress.Id);

        PublicInfoModel model = new PublicInfoModel();

        model.FirstName = address.FirstName;
        model.LastName = address.LastName;
        model.Address1 = address.Address1;
        model.Address2 = address.Address2;
        model.City = address.City;
        model.StateProvinceId = 1;
        model.StateProvinceName = address.StateProvince.Name;
        model.CountryId = 1;
        model.CountryName = address.Country.TwoLetterIsoCode;
        model.PostalCode = address.ZipPostalCode;

        return PartialView("Nop.Plugin.Widgets.AddressVerification.Views.WidgetsAddressVerification.PublicInfo", model);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this. it's getting into the partialviewresult correctly, but now it's not opening the dialog window and showing the information.

Comment: what are you using for your modal code?  I was using bootstrap hence the .modal('show') command.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery by default works in asynchronous mode.

While doing post using

```
$.post(url, { id: selectedShippingAddressId });
```

you can use

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { id: selectedShippingAddressId },
    success: success,
    type: 'POST',
    async:false
});
```

Now pop will always load when above code gone through processing.