# Pass Value of Drop Down as a Route Value to an Ajax Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, viewmodel

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC4 application, and I have the following in one of my views:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetAllOrangeChocs", "ChocFactory", new { area = "Provider", Id = Model.FruitId }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "ChocFruitWrap" }, null))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="col-md-2 control-label"><strong>Fruit Group:</strong></span>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FruitlId, new SelectList(Model.ListOf_Fruits,"Id", "PortalDisplayName"),"--Please Select--")
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group col-md-1">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
}
```

So it is an Ajax form that calls some controller action that returns a PartialView to display on the page. The controller code is:

```
public PartialViewResult GetAllOrangeChocs(int Id)
{
    var model = _service.GetMeSomethingUsefulWithPassedParam(Id);
    return PartialView("_Categories", model);
}
```

My controller action is being hit, but the Id is always `null`, my guess is, it is because there is no two way binding in place! As the ViewModel is passed in the `GET` Request, the `FruitId` on the ViewModel is `null`, and it only actually gets set in the `POST`

Am I right in my reasoning? And if yes ... how can I easily pass the Value (the Id) of the selected item in the Drop Down list?

I know I can added a hidden field, and via jQuery populate it each time the drop down changes, but is there no cleaner way?

Comment: for loading a partial view I always use an ajax call instead of an ajax form.  see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643864/how-do-i-render-a-partial-form-element-using-ajax/19643974#19643974

Comment: Thanks Matt. But how does that fix the issue with the Drop Down value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the link you have an ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetAllOrangeChocs", "ChocFactory")',
    data: {
        Selected: $('#FruitlId').val()
    }
    success: function (result) {
         $('.divContent').html(result);
    }
});
```

through the data attribute you can send whatever you want.  What I have here will put the selected value into a variable called Selector (make sure whatever you call it on the view matches exactly with the input parameter on the controller).  Let me know if you have any questions.