# Update partial view with jQuery after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to update partial view when ajax call is triggered in the main view. This is what I have so far, the partial view:

```
@using System.Globalization
@model Application.Domain.Entities.Cart

<div class="navbar-right">
     <img src="../../Images/cart2.png" alt="" />
    @Model.Items.Sum(x=>x.Quantity) item(s),
    @Model.ComputeTotalValue().ToString("c", new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
    @Html.ActionLink("Checkout", "Index", "Cart",
        new {returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery},
        new {@class="btn btn-warning btn-sm navbar-btn"}
        )
</div>
```

Then, in the _Layout.cshtml file I'm including the partial view in the header:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">                    
                  <a href="/">
<img class="navbar-left navbar-brand" src="@Url.Action("GetStoreImage", "Home")"/></a>
                            @Html.Action("Summary", "Cart")       
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In the main view I have this jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {      
        $('button.submitButton').click(function () {            
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AddToCartAjax", "Cart")',
                data: { itemId: $(this).data('id'), categoryId: $(this).data('categoryid') },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                //Update partial view here, partial view is cart total                      
                    $(".modal-body #cartTotalLabel").text(data);
                    $('#createModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });
        $('#accordion').on('click', function () {
            $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
        });        
    });
    </script>
```

How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643864/how-do-i-render-a-partial-form-element-using-ajax/19643974#19643974

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a container div where partial view will be loaded:

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Create a function which will send ajax call to an action and return updated partial view form it and call that function in the success of the current ajax call.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {      
        $('button.submitButton').click(function () {            
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AddToCartAjax", "Cart")',
                data: { itemId: $(this).data('id'), categoryId: $(this).data('categoryid') },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                //Update partial view here, partial view is cart total
                    UpdatePartiaView();       
                    $(".modal-body #cartTotalLabel").text(data);
                    $('#createModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
        });
        $('#accordion').on('click', function () {
            $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
        });        
    });

function UpdatePartialView()
{
// send another ajax call and append the html returned in container
}
    </script>
```