# MVC4 Partial View Error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

First of I am a complete beginner at MVC. How would I be able to display data from the database in the events table  in a partial view if a certain boolean field is true.

This is my partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TheBigEvent.Models.RecommendedEvents>
<table>
 <tr>

  <td>  
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Event_Name)
      </td>
      <td>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Event_Date)

   </td>
  </tr>

 <tr>   

      @foreach (var item in Model) {

          <td>  

    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Event_Name)
</td>
     <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Event_Date)
         </td>
     }

 </tr>                          
   </table>
```

This is my controller

```
public ActionResult _RecommendedEvents()

    {


        var recommendedevents = from Events in db.Database1
                                select Events;

        recommendedevents = recommendedevents.Where(s => s.Recommended.Equals(true));

        return PartialView("_RecommendEvents", recommendedevents);


    }
```

And the Code for displaying the partialview

```
 @Html.Partial("_RecommmndedEvents")
```

This is the error I am receiving

[image]

[EDIT]

```
 public ActionResult _RecommendedEvents(RecommendedEvents model)

    {

        model = new RecommendedEvents();


        var recommendedevents = from Events in db.Database1
                                select Events;


        recommendedevents = recommendedevents.Where(s => s.Recommended.Equals(true));








        return View(model);


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@{
        Html.RenderAction("view","controller")
}
```

This will go to the given controller and action that has to return a partialview with the correct model

Answer (score 1):

object reference not set to an instance of an object has always been an un initialized list for me.  try initializing recommendedevents before setting it.  something like

```
List<Events> recommendedevents = new List<Events>();
```

replacing Events with whatever the type is.

the first parameter in Html.Partial is the partial name not the method call.  you need to either pass the model to your view thought a view model and pass it to the partial

```
@Html.Partial("_RecommendedEvents", Model.Events)
```

or load the partial through an ajax call.  see my answer here for an example [How do I render a partial form element using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643864/how-do-i-render-a-partial-form-element-using-ajax/19643974#19643974)

Answer (score 0):

The `@HTML.Partial()` function does not go through any controller action to render, it just renders the View's HTML in that spot in the document. And you aren't passing in the `IEnumerable<TheBigEvent.Models.RecommendedEvents>` to that partial view, so when that partial renders, the `Model` is null.

Put the `IEnumerable<TheBigEvent.Models.RecommendedEvents>` object into your main page's View Model, or maybe on something in the ViewBag, and pass it to the partial view at the time you call the Partial method:

`@HTML.Partial("_RecommmndedEvents", ViewBag.RecommendedEvents)`

In the top-level page's controller action, set that `ViewBag.RecommendedEvents` just like how you are instantiating it in your controller code above.

Comment: Okay so i have put     @model IEnumerable<TheBigEvent.Models.RecommendedEvents> in the view. and added the Model to the partial as  @Html.Partial("_RecommendedEvents", Model); but its still coming up with the same error

Comment: Are you instantiating it in the top-level controller action? The action you posted in your question is not getting executed, so you'll need to call that repo code and pass that object as the model to the top level view. Post that controller action as an edit to your question.

Comment: Here you go. Im not sure what you mean by top level controller action

Comment: You instantiate the `model` var in that Action and return it without altering it in any way . I doubt that is correct. Did you mean to `return View(recommendedevents);`?

Comment: Yes I have fixed that now, its still giving me the same error though regardless

Comment: Remove all the code you provided in your original question, and put in all the new code you've got running now. We still haven't seen the first controller action that gets called, and that's where you'll have to instantiate the object you pass to the partial view.

Comment: Ive gotten the partial view to work now. The only problem is that the partial view is on the layout view I can access my index page by calling _RecommendedEvents(); the problem now is that when i click onto another page it gives me back that error, any suggestions?

Comment: Well if this partial is hooked into your Layout view, that means that you need to attach the List<RecommendedEvents> to every Action in your app. I'd suggest opening up another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

The error means your model is null,
`PartialView()` is used when you are using `Ajax`, otherwise you can write your code as below :

```
return View("_RecommendEvents", recommendedevents);
```