# MVC Routing and Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ok I have 2 two questions:

1 - I have a view that returns a list of member's images. If you click on image it needs to display member info in the same view but now I get following error:

*The current request for action 'ViewMembers' on controller type 'HomeController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ViewMembers(Int32) on type ServingTeam.Controllers.HomeController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ViewMembers() on type ServingTeam.Controllers.HomeController*

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ViewMembers()
{
    TempData["returnMember"] = false;

    List<Members> members = memberRepo.GetAllMembers();

    return View(members);
}

[ActionName("ViewMembers")]
public ActionResult ViewMembers(int slug) 
{
    Members member = new Members();

    member = memberRepo.GetMember(slug);

    if (member != null)
        return View(member);

    return View("ViewMembers");
}
```

2 - How do I display single object within the view that display the list of members? I have created a partial view to display the member's info but it does not allow me to do so.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: use an ajax call for populating the partial view.  see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643864/how-do-i-render-a-partial-form-element-using-ajax/19643974#19643974.  using the ajax call you can change the method name to something unique to get the other error to go away

Comment: I don't want to make use of an ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two controller actions (methods) that have the same route. You'd need to rename one of them. You can still return the same view from both. I suggest renaming the second one into `ViewMember`.

For the second part of the question:

If you insist on using the same view for both: displaying list of members and displaying "selected" member info, then either add `SelectedMember` property to your model or add it to the `ViewBag` and pass that into your partial view. So, your action could look like this:

```
public ActionResult ViewMember(int slug) 
{
    List<Members> members = memberRepo.GetAllMembers();
    Member member = memberRepo.GetMember(slug);

    ViewBag["SelectedMember"] = member;

    return View("ViewMembers", members);
}
```

Make sure to check if `ViewBag["SelectedMember"]` is not `null` before you render the partial view, or handle the `null` case in the partial view.

Comment: The thing is I want to return the member's info within the same view that the list is in

Comment: Will ViewBag["SelectedMember"] actually have propterties like the orignal object? Will I able to use it like ViewBag["SelectedMember"].Name?

Comment: You will pass value of `ViewBag["SelectedMember"]` into your partial view. From there on in the partial view you'd work with the model normally and use `Model.Name` etc.

Comment: I am not sure how to accomplish this, can you perhaps post some code for me?

Comment: If you post relevant pieces of your view and partial view I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making two different actions. one action can do the job for you:

```
[ActionName("ViewMembers")]
public ActionResult ViewMembers(int slug=0) 
{
    if(slug > 0)
    {
    Members member = null;

    member = memberRepo.GetMember(slug);

    if (member != null)
        return View(member);

    return View("ViewMembers");
    }
    else
    {
     TempData["returnMember"] = false;

     List<Members> members = memberRepo.GetAllMembers();

     return View(members);
    }

}
```

Comment: No need for `= New Member()` should just be `= null`, that way you don't construct an object that is never used.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad this is not going to work for me, I always need to have all members. I need to display partial view when user want to see a certain member's info

Comment: you can return partial view as well, whats the issue

Comment: The issue I have is I cant return single object within a view that return List<>. Partial View return single object

Comment: in the if you can return partial view and in else you can return view isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not using `TempData` or the `ViewBag`, because both are not-strongly typed,  intuitive (for you or anyone else looking at your code), hard to maintain, etc etc.  First create your ViewModel:

```
public class ViewMemberViewModel
{
  public ViewMemberViewModel()
  {
    // I like having my classes in valid states 
    // before the constructor finishes
    this.Members = new List<Member>();
  }      


  public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Next, create a single action with a `Nullable<int>`.  Why nullable?  Because using [magic numbers (type #3)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) are typically not the best way to describe not having a value.  Not having a value, is already created in the framework (null).  This is very similar to [Ehsan Sajjad's anwswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23234746/209259).

```
public ActionResult ViewMembers(int? slug) 
{
  var model = new ViewMemberViewModel();

  if (slug.HasValue)
  {
    var member = memberRepo.GetMember(slug);
    model.Members.Add(member);
  }
  else
  {
    var members = memberRepo.GetAllMembers();
    model.Members.AddRange(members);
  }

  return View(members);
}
```

With a nice view:

```
@model ViewMemberViewModel

@foreach(var member in Model.Members)
{
  // The Controller already uses logic
  // to return 1 or more members.
}

@* don't forget if there aren't any *@
@if (Model.Members.Count == 0)
{
  // No members to display
}
```

Comment: I like the logic but in my case it will not work. All members need to be returned

Comment: Either your question isn't very clear, or you aren't understanding my design.  This design returns either all the members or a single member.  The view also allows for all members or a single member.  I don't see the issue.