# Calling MVC Action Methods from JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="AddAccounts" value="AddAccountsToUser" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Controller.cs

```
 public ActionResult AddSitesToUserSubmit(){}
```

How to call a controller onClick of Submit button using javascript:

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: ajax calls.  see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643864/how-do-i-render-a-partial-form-element-using-ajax/19643974#19643974

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  A `submit` button submitting a form to the server will already invoke the action method.  Are you trying to invoke a different action method?  Invoke it without refreshing the page?  Something else?